# Index.html as welcome page in spring+angularJS application

Tags: java, angularjs, spring, spring-mvc, ngboilerplate

Have an application with SpringMVC+AngularJS. Have place the index.html page in
src/main/webapp/app/src/index.html.

In web.xml have

```
<welcome-file-list>  
  <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>  
</welcome-file-list>
```

The application works with

http://localhost:8080/myapp/app/index.html

But not with 
http://localhost:8080/myapp
What changes should be made so that the application is directed to the index.html page correctly

Answer (score 0):

Try to replace

```
<welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
```

with

```
<welcome-file>app/index.html</welcome-file>
```

Comment: Getting http 404 with this

Comment: then  try to move your index.html so that it is reachable with the URL http://localhost:8080/myapp/index.html

Comment: The code is generated using ngboilerplate. Cant move the index.html

Comment: Can you mention the location of index.html file? Normally in spring application to get the welcome file you need to give the relative path of the file.

Comment: index.html in not in WEB-INF. when you will hit the dispatcher servlet, It will redirect the request to view resolver where it won't find this file. Please refer below answer to make it work.

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming that you have any `InternalResourceViewResolver` configured.
You have to make 2 changes.
1. 
  Change welcome-file in web.xml like below

```
<welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>app/src/index.html</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>`
```

2. change dispatcher-servlet.xml or whatever configuration file you have like below
   `<mvc:resources mapping="/app/src/**" location="/app/src/"/>
   <mvc:default-servlet-handler />`

You can google for annotations for above configuration if you are having annotation based configuration.